# How should I read 歳 here?

Tags: readings

> 七つの**歳**

It's somebody's age. It's like 七歳, isn't it? Is it read as さい or とし?

Comment: By the way, I feel this use of 歳 strange, as  七つのとし likely mean "the year when (someone specified in the context) was (/will be) 7 years old", probably not "the age of seven". Is it just alternatively used in the same meaning as 年 or my latter interpretation is also true here?

Comment: ^ 七つの歳 means "the age of seven" and it doesn't sound strange to me.

Comment: @rk03 どんなに短くてもコメント欄で回答をしないようにお願いします。単に[サイトのルールに違反しています](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/593/5010)し、システムに「未回答の質問」扱いされつづけてしまうことによる[実害](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99672/719822)があります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's read ななつのとし, and it means "the age of 7". さい is a unit ("-year-old"), but it's not used as a noun on its own.